# É aconselhável manter uma zTable sempre aberta?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cadastro de produtos e frente de caixa.

Meu Form principal é a tela de Pedidos e a partir dele os abro as demais telas de cadastro (Unidade de Medida, Produtos, Formas de Pagamento, Clientes, entre outras)

Para cada uma dessas telas possuo uma zTable em um Data Módule. E no OnShow/OnClose de cada form, abro/fecho as zTables.

Como na tela principal eu necessito dessas zTables abertas, minha dúvida é a seguinte: É aconselhável eu abrí-las no form principal e mantê-las aberta durante todo o tempo que minha aplicação ficar rodando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso tem de ser visto por 2 lados

### 1. Qual a frequencia de alteração destas tabelas?

Se elas não forem atualizadas com frequencia, vale a pena as manter abertas, mas deve tomar cuidado para que a informação não fique desatualizada

### 2. Qual o tamanho destas tabelas?

Se elas possuirem muitos dados, se elas ficarem abertas podem ocupar muita memória, e dependendo do dispositivo que forem rodar, pode ser impeditivo.

### Quanto a onde mantê-las abertas:

Uma ideia interessante é criar um ojeto **Singleton** como cache de dados genéricos para sua aplicação, não necessariamente no form principal, para evitar dependências muito complexas.

Além disso implementar um conceito de LazyLoad, só carregar esses dados para a memória depois da primeira solicitação.

```
TDadosCache = class
private
  FUnidadesMedida: TZTable
published
  property UnidadesMedida: TZTable read GetUnidadesMedida;
end;

function TDadosCache.GetUnidadesMedida: TZTable;
begin
  if not FUnidadesMedida.Active then
    FUnidadesMedida.Open;

  Result := FUnidadesMedida;
end;
```

Comment: Acho que entendi @Caputo. Então ao invés de eu utilizar `ztUnidadesMedida.Open` eu utilizaria `GetUnidadesMedida` do objeto `DadosCache`, correto? E para definir que meu `FUnidadesMedida` é minha zTable `ztUnidadesMedida`, faço isso no construtor do objeto, correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo @ThiagoThaison, assim você mantém todo o cache em um único local e, caso alguém trabalhe no financeiro, por exemplo, pode não precisar de todos estes dados abertos. O método Get ficaria encapsulado na property, daí vc usaria `Cache.UnidadesMedida`